# What is the meaning of GY-X nomenclature in chips?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have a pressure sensor that is using the chip MS5611.
But, the "board" say: "GY-63"

[image: MS5611 Gy-63 chip]

I understand that the MS5611 is the "internal" chip, where the magic comes, but, what is the meaning of "GY-63"?

If I have to call this "sensor/module/chip" with a name, which should be that name? GY-63? MS6511? Which name identify this "thing" as an unique identification (ID)?

Sorry for mix up a lot of concepts. I'm a web developer. I'm not familiarized with this naming conventions.

ADDED:
For example, I have a GY-68, GY-63, GY-GPS6MV1, and 4 or 5 more of them

Comment: Sounds like the module model number to me.

Comment: Yes, MS5611 is the actual pressure sensor from TE. http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-CAT-BLPS0036.html And the GY-63 is the name of that particular breakout board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a model number for the breakout board. It doesn't have any deeper meaning.

A quick search finds a number of other sensor breakout boards with similar names, e.g.

- GY-21, a humidity sensor
- GY-31, a color sensor
- GY-52, an accelerometer/gyroscope
- GY-291, another accelerometer

Most of these appear to be ad-hoc names used by small Chinese manufacturers. If you need to describe these boards, make sure to reference the name of the part on the board (e.g, "MS5611"), as it will be easier for others to find than the specific breakout you used.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is this just a market model but perhaps the engineers suggested it by the 20 log ratio of max /min atmospheric pressure for Y axis and ( has some other meaning like Good for Y axis ratio of 63dB GY-63

Check out and compare BG's GY-63 with GY-68 where they specify input noise equivalent to 17 cm for altitude.  But then could not guarantee it & commit to spec.. only best case maybe...